# Replace docker image with build from another directory

Tags: ubuntu, docker, deployment, docker-compose, dockerfile

On a Ubuntu server I have a docker image running which was built from a git repository cloned into directory_a. In directory_b I have another clone of the same repo, but with several differences relating to ownership, git ignored files, and using a different branch. Going forward, directory_b will be the new working directory. My question is, how do I replace the current build with a new one from directory_b?

The `Dockerfile` and `docker-compose.yml` files are identical between the two copies and, unless I change it, the new image will have the same name as the old. Is that something that should be changed?

I was not involved in the initial setup and don't have much experience with Docker, and really, really do not want to break anything. It looks like I can use

```
docker-compose build <service_name>
docker-compose stop <service_name>
docker-compose up -d --no-deps <service_name>
```

to replace the current build with a new one, but I am concerned that the different source will cause an issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest tagging your image with a new version number. If you're using `docker-compose build` you would want to make sure you're specifying an `image` key with a tag. For instance:
version: '3'
services:
  webapp:
    build: .
    image: myimage:2.0

You can find more info in the [Compose File reference](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#build). Also Docker has published a [Best Practices for Working with Dockerfiles](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/).

Once you have versioned it, you want to make sure it's stored in a registry Docker Hub/Docker Cloud, or a Docker Trusted Registry, or the open source Docker Registry are all candidates. Make sure you know which registry your team wants to work with (likely they are using one already) and push the image there.